# Calculating and deleting JSON data

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, frontend

I'm quite confused how to calculate data json that i have. I have data json 
"id" : "001","item" : "samsung","quantity" : 2, "price" : $300. first i want to calculate subtotal = quantity*price. and that works. but i dont have idea how to calculate total. anybody can help?
this is js that hold data json

```
export function DataBarang () {
        return  [{
                "id" : "001",
                "item" : "samsung",
                "quantity" : 1,
                "price" : 300,

            },
            {
                "id" : "002",
                "item" : "iphone",
                "quantity" : 2,
                "price" : 450,

            }];
    }
```

and than this is table that display data

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DataBarang } from './Barang';

class cart extends Component{
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        json: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState((prevState) => {
        return {
            json: DataBarang()
        }
    })
}
render (){
    return (

        <table id="cart" className="table table-hover table-condensed">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th styles="width:50%" className="text-center">Item</th>
                                <th styles="width:10%" className="text-center">Price</th>
                                <th styles="width:8%" className="text-center">Quantity</th>
                                <th styles="width:22%" className="text-center">Subtotal</th>
                                <th styles="width:10%" className="text-center">Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        {this.state.json.map((data, i) => {
                            var subtotal = data.price*data.quantity;
                            var total = total+subtotal;
                        return (
                            <tr key={i}>
                                <td data-th="Product">
                                    <div className="row">
                                        <img src={} alt="..." className="img-responsive"/>
                                        <div className="col-sm-10">
                                            <h4 className="nomargin">{data.item}</h4>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="Price">Rp.{data.price}</td>
                                <td data-th="Quantity">
                                    <input type="number" className="form-control" value={data.quantity}/>
                                </td>
                                <td data-th="Subtotal" className="text-center">Rp.{subtotal}</td>
                                <td className="actions" data-th="">
                                    <button className="button is-danger"><i className="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>                             
                                </td>
                            </tr>);
                        })}  
                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>


                            <tr>
                                <td><Link to ="/" className="button is-warning"><i className="fa fa-angle-left"></i> Lanjut Berbelanja</Link></td>
                                <td colspan="2" className="hidden-xs"></td>
                                <td className="hidden-xs text-center"><strong>Total Rp. {}</strong></td>
                                <td><a href="#" className="button is-success">Checkout <i className="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>)

                        </tfoot>
                    </table>

    );

}
}

export default cart;
```

and tell me how to delete data using button () onClick

Comment: What do you mean by delete data? What is rendered, what activates it, and what gets unmounted/deleted?

Comment: To delete data on ui level, just remove it from state. But I guess you have to delete data from database. In this case the best way is use one of flux libs and proceed according to their workflow

Comment: @Andrew i want to delete data in function DataBarang(). i displayed that data in a table and I created a button to delete data in each data in the table.

Comment: @ZoreslavGoral just delete on ui. because I just do a test on my ui. and has not been connected to the backend and database

Comment: Ah, I understand. Give me a bit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to sum up the entire JSON you receive of `quantity * price`, then you can do it as a separate calculation.

```js
const json = [{
    "id" : "001",
    "item" : "samsung",
    "quantity" : 1,
    "price" : 300,

},
{
    "id" : "002",
    "item" : "iphone",
    "quantity" : 2,
    "price" : 450,

}];

const total = json.map(({quantity, price}) => quantity * price)
                  .reduce((a, b) => a + b)
console.log(total)
```

In order to handle a delete, make a new function that accepts the id of the element that uses `filter` to remove it from your `this.state.json`. Here is a barebones example.

```
handleDelete(id) {
  const filteredJSON = this.state.json.filter(item => {
    return item.id !== id
  })
  this.setState({json: filteredJSON})
}

render() {
  return (
<div>
    {this.state.json.map((data, i) => {
      const id = data.id
      return (
        <div>
          {data.item}
          <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(id)}>
            {'delete'}
          </button>
        </div>
      )
    })}
</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: but i found nothing happened when i clicked the delete button. I've implemented your code. please tell me more. @Andrew

Comment: @RiyanMaulana I made a small mistake. I needed to change `item` to `item.id` inside the `filter`. I've edited it with that fix.